# Linq Data Mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have an old system with a lot of stored procedures that I am redeveloping using C# and MVC. I created Entities base on the system and I use Entity Framework as ORM. What is the best practice to map output of an stored procedure that includes some joins to my entities.
For example I have table1, table2 and table3 then I have and stored procedure includes:

```
Select * from table1 join table2 on ...
join table3 on ..
```

then I want the entities be filled by this data and in my controllers I use linq for accessing  this data
As I have this three table I created three entities:

```
class table1{
public int table1Id;
public String value{get;set;}
public IEnumarable<table2> table2List{get;set;}
}
class table2{
public int table2Id{get;set;}
public String table2value{get;set;}
public IEnumarable<table3> table3List{get;set;}
}
```

I just added some pseudo code to make it clear. I want to map output of stored procedure to these entities.

Comment: The question is not clear and hard to understand, perhaps show the code you have tried so far in linq  / controller and what's blocking you to achieve that?

Comment: Are you going to use the SP's? You could create types that match the return *dataset* of the SP

Comment: I know that but in this case If I had 100 SP I need to create 100 new sp_result type or call each SP myself and then try to fill entities. I think there are some better ways to do that

Comment: ...or you'll re-write the 100 or so SP's as LINQ statements? is every SP a `SELECT`? since `GetCustomer`, `GetCustomers`, `InsertCustomer`, `UpdateCustomer` etc would all have one *Entity*, `Customer`.

Comment: Sorry it is not clear enough. By the way, I am just looking for best practice. something like a mapping library

Comment: AutoMapper, AutoFac ?